# How to remove apostrophe and whitespace in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *str = @"mario's test";
NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

With this function I can remove the white space, but I also need to remove the apostrophe `'`:

```
stringWithoutSpaces = "mariostest"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
*stringWithoutSpaces = [[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]
                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""];
```